# What is the most effective linux program to perminanlty delete a file?

Tags: linux, bash

Some people recommend, whipe, srm, shred, etc. Is there one best assuming that the goal is to make a file irretrievable, regardless of time/space taken to delete?

It would also be great if you could explain why the program is best.

Comment: By *regardless of resources taken* I assume you mean effort spent trying to recover the data?

Comment: I edited the question to make more sense.

Comment: Actually it's more confusing now. Do you really mean resources taken to *delete*, or rather to *recover*?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to render a file unrecoverable by undelete utilities, [the `secure-delete` package](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tools-to-delete-files-securely-in-ubuntu-linux.html) includes a utility called `sfill` which will fill up all the free space on your disk with random data.  Do this after deleting files you don't want recovered.  (A Sysinternals utility called SDelete does a similar thing on Windows).

From reading the `shred` man page (`shred` being an often-citied utility that purports to make files unrecoverable) opening the file, writing random data from byte 0 to the length of that file may not cause new data to be written entirely in place of the old due to how journaling filesystems work.  ext2 is not a journaling filesystem (ext3 and ext4 are).

I'm unsure if or of how `srm` in that same `secure-delete` suite of utilities achieves anything differently than `shred` though.

Comment: srm passes 350 times (by default) over the blocks where the file was. It does this only for files and it doesn't write random data to empty blocks. As detailed in ''man srm''